# How can I remove anti-aliasing color artifacts using Gimp?

Tags: gimp, photo-editing

I have been working on vectorizing a series of 604 photos for a very long time. After all that, I figured that the best way to vectorize such a photo is to:

1. Turn it to solid colors (i.e. remove the anti-aliasing color artifacts around the text.)
2. Enlarge it
3. Remove Anti-aliasing artifacts again?
4. Vectorize.

This is put in general, of course there are things I have to do between these steps (I was told that by someone who was helping me on this project, if you want to see the discussion, I have it [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94991/discussion-on-answer-by-user287001-how-can-i-remove-all-blurs-from-text-in-multi)) which I still don't understand.

Anyways, here's one of the images:

[image]

If you zoom in, you'll see that the colors have many shades, I want to turn them to one (In the bottom of the page, you can see all the colors that I want to stay, which are: blue, dark blue, green, grey, orange, yellow, pink, dark pink, and also with the addition of black and white, green and dark green, and the shape of yellow that can be seen at those circles, they represent the end of a verse and they have an Arabic number in them, and there are seven of them.). I heard from [someone](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94991/discussion-on-answer-by-user287001-how-can-i-remove-all-blurs-from-text-in-multi) that GIMP has many new layer blending modes which can help me remove these anti-aliasing artifacts, how can I use those?

Comment: I've edited your question to help clarify what it is you are seeking. I am not a GIMP user, and can not directly assist with GIMP. Sorry.

Comment: Brother no problem, any software that can do that is fine, it doesn't have to be GIMP

Comment: I removed most of the comments because I think they are obsolete by now. If you feel that anything still needs to be addressed, please re-post it.

Comment: It is possible to remove the anti aliasing when this photo is with such low quality?